# Usage of onwards

Tags: adverbs, exam-questions

Which option is correct ?

---

Following World War II, European countries largely gave up their colonial possessions and, **by the 1950s and 1960s**, had already begun to receive growing numbers of immigrants from their former colonies. In many instances, these included the descendants of the slaves in the colonies, who had been forced to work. In this respect, Britain is a case in point. Though in small numbers, Africans and Indians had come to Britain long before the tens of thousands who came as colonial immigrants in the 1960s and thereafter. 
It is stressed in the passage that Britain.........................

A. was faced soon after World War II with an enormous influx of immigrants

B. began to receive huge numbers of colonial immigrants from the 1960s onwards

---

I thought the answer was A because WW2 ended before 1950 and the passage says the immigrants had already begun to go to Britain by 1950, but the answer is B according the key..It seems wrong because "from the 1960s onwards" means the years that starts 1960 and the ones comes later. So I wonder what the point  I miss is?

Comment: The 1950s and 1960s indicates "growing numbers of immigrants", but we don't know how many (it could have been 100 to 1000, but not "enormous"). Then, "the tens of thousands who came as colonial immigrants in the 1960s and thereafter". You have the meaning of *onwards* correct. This has more to do with reading comprehension regarding series of events.

Answer (score 2):

The question about your passage is actually a very good one for reading comprehension.

Although your passage in the beginning says

> by the 1950s and 1960s, had already begun to receive growing numbers of immigrants

later on it is stated

> Though in small numbers, Africans and Indians had come to Britain long before

indicating the original number were small compared to

> the tens of thousands who came as colonial immigrants in the 1960s and thereafter...

meaning the bulk of immigration was after the 1960's.

> "1960s onwards" = "1960s and thereafter"

To correctly answer the question, the entire passage would have had to have been read and the chronology understood.